# Continue after incorrect input for loop

Tags: c, arrays, input, continue

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define M 6
#define N 5


int main(){

  int array[N][M];
  int i, j;

  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<M;j++){
        scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
        if(array[0][1]<1 || array[0][2]<1 || array[0][3]<1){
            // ??
        }

    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

How do I make it so that if the input doesn't match my (very likely wrong) if statement, the
        user must reinput that array field and it doesnt just skip to the next input field?

Comment: Put the `scanf` in a while loop with the condition of the while loop only set to false if the input is verified.

Comment: First, you should initialize your array so that your condition passes (memset to 1 or something), otherwise you might never make progress.  Then you can do something like `printf("Invalid. Reenter.\n"); j--; continue;`.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I make it so that if the input doesn't match my (very likely wrong) if statement, the
>   user must reinput that array field and it doesnt just skip to the next input field?

You can have the condition of your `if` statement determine how the loop variables (that serve as array indexes) are updated:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++){     // dont update i here
    for(j=0;j<M;j++){ // dont update j here
```

Instead use a `while` loop that updates `i` and `j` if your condition is satisfied as well as if there are any rows and columns left:

```
while(1) {
    printf("Enter value: ");
    scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
    printf("array[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, array[i][j]);
    if(YOUR_CONDITION) {

        // update i and j inside this statement
        // this means the user can advance to the next array element
        // ONLY if your if statement condition is true

        if(j < M-1) { // if there are columns left, update j
            j++;
        }
        else if(i < N-1) { // otherwise, if there are rows left, reset j and update i
              j = 0; 
              i++; 
        } else {
            break;  // if we reach this point we are out of rows and columns and we break out of the loop
        } 
    } else {
          printf("Please satisfy the condition!\n");
    }
}
```

Now, as far as `YOUR_CONDITION`:

```
if(array[0][1]<1 || array[0][2]<1 || array[0][3]<1)
```

The problem with this statement is that it is checking values in the array that weren't yet entered by the user.

If you specify what you want to do with this statement, maybe I can be of further help.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you can simple do the following. If input is wrong, decrement j by 1 to force the user to reinput the same field. It may also make sense to tell the user that their input was wrong, so they know to enter the proper value.